# Display DataGridView based on ComboBox value

Tags: c#

I want to display datagridview based on value of combobox
for example
combobox value is 2
i want to show two datagrid
combobox value is 1
display 1 datagrid

which event handler is used for this coding?? anyone please help me...

Comment: your combo box  fill  value is statically or dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

First you have create combobox `SelectedIndexChanged` event and inside called `FillGridview()` method.

```
 private void combobox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FillGridview();
        }
```

then inside method you can check combobox value.

```
    private void  FillGridview()
    {
        if (combobox.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
             Datagrid2.Visible = false;
             Datagrid1.Visible = true;
        }
        else if (combobox.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
             Datagrid2.Visible = true;
             Datagrid1.Visible = false;              
        }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get current value in Combobox, use

```
    string str = comboBoxName.Text
```

If you want to know when the selected value changed, double click to the combobox on the form design, Visual Studio will generate event method for you, something like bellow :

```
    private void comboBoxName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = comboBoxName.Text;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void combobox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        Datagrid2.Visible = false;
        Datagrid1.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {   Datagrid1.Visible = false;
        Datagrid2.Visible = true;
    }
}
```